# How do i select element with a wildcard in attribute name?

Tags: xpath, wildcard, html-agility-pack

i have this HTML tag :

```
<div id="23a521b6-5a90-4257-9ee3-17a2cbe8a8fc" jquery17208007497985234224="13"  jquery172080076755224="4"></div>
```

I need help to select this div where the attribute name is jquery* for clean up, the final result will be:

```
<div id="23a521b6-5a90-4257-9ee3-17a2cbe8a8fc"></div>
```

Thanks,
chapas

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what technologies you are using for this, but to get rid of these attributes using XSLT do:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*[starts-with(local-name(), 'jquery')]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd select all the attributes which start with `jquery` string, and then remove them by using AgilityPack:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var attributes = doc.DocumentNode
    .Descendants()
    .SelectMany(n => n.Attributes.Cast<HtmlAttribute>())
    .Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith("jquery"))
    .ToArray();

foreach (var attribute in attributes)
    attribute.Remove();
```

This will give you something like:

```
<div id="23a521b6-5a90-4257-9ee3-17a2cbe8a8fc"></div>
```